# why does a full adder take in 3 numbers and not 2

Tags: combinatorics, nand2tetris

So I was asked a question in uni and after a having a look I really couldn't find an answer. Why does a full adder takes in 3 number and not 2. Is it so that it can retain the carry from the 1st half adder?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the course you can see, and should learn to distinguish, 3 types of adders:

1. Half-adder, that can perform addition of two bits from input and output two 1 - bit values : sum and carry.
2. Full-adder: Does exactly the same thing as Half-adder but has additional third 1-bit input, most likely being carry from some previous adding result, but not necessarily.
3. n-bit adder: had two n-bit wide inputs and one n bit output, it's internal design performs addition of two numbers given as input.

That being said - full adder has third input to perform addition of three 1-bit inputs, it's most likely that one would use the third bit to feed it with carry, but not always. You can always build nice incrementer with feeding this 3rd input with constant logical true.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You’re correct.

Imagine you want to add multiple bits:

```
01
01
```

You can use a half adder in the right-most column. This results in 0 with a carry.

You need to give that carry to the next adder for the left-most column. Hence a full adder needs three inputs, 0 and 0 and 1 in our example, giving us 1.

```
10
```